# How to receive server-sent events (SSE) in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, server-sent-events, flutter-http, event-stream

I have tried several different SSE-plugins to receive server-sent events in a Flutter Web app, and all of them can connect but I don't receive any events in Flutter. However, if I open DevTools in Chrome and go to Network -> EventStream, I see the events coming in from the server. What could be the reason I don't receive them in the app?

I have tried [sse](https://pub.dev/packages/sse), [sse_client](https://pub.dev/packages/sse_client) and [eventsource](https://pub.dev/packages/eventsource), but the result is the same in all of them.

Here's how I implemented the app using the [sse_client](https://pub.dev/packages/sse_client) plugin:

```
sseClient = SseClient.connect(Uri.parse('https://example.com/test-sse/index.php'));
print('sse connected');

sseClient.stream.listen(
    (event) {
      print('sse event: ${event.toString()}');
  },
  onError: (err){
    print('sse error');
  },
  onDone: (){
    print('sse closed');
  },
);
```

The only output I get is `sse connected`, and then nothing - even though the events keep coming in the DevTools Network/EventStream tab.

Here's my PHP test script:

```
<?php

ob_end_clean();

set_time_limit(60);

while (true) {
    // Headers must be processed line by line.
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:56008');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream; charset=utf-8');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

    $data = [
        'message' => 'Event: server-time='.date('G:H:s', time()),
        'dummy' => str_repeat(' ',1024*64)
    ];
    print("id: ".microtime()."\n");
    print("event: ping\n");
    print('data: '.json_encode($data)."\n");
    print("\n");

    ob_flush();
    flush();
    
    sleep(1);
}
```

I have tried removing the `id` and the `dummy` etc., but the result is the same - the browser receives the events, but the app doesn't receive anything.

Comment: Facing the same issue. The http package (used by almost all the libraries for sse) does not recieve events in chunks. It receives in one go. If you close the connection server side, it gets all the events as one big chunk. Only happens in web. Desktop, iOS & Android fine.

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/337

Comment: Here's the culprit - "It is also unable to stream requests or responses; a request will only be sent and a response will only be returned once all the data is available." - [BrowserClient](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/browser_client/BrowserClient-class.html)

Comment: what did you end up doing?

Comment: @Srikanth I ended up using SignalR instead, which is a Microsoft open source "protocol" to open a client-server connection. I'm using the signalr_netcore Flutter plugin, and on the server side an ASP.NET Core web application written in Visual Studio. I think this is a better solution than Server-Sent Events via PHP, which as far as I understand will eat up a lot of server resources when the number of simultaneous connections increase.

Comment: Thanks. I guess we have no choice but to switch to websockets.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fetch_client`](https://pub.dev/packages/fetch_client) at web until [this open Flutter issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/337) is resolved.

`sse_stream.dart`: Get stream on Android/iOS/Mac/Windows:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart';

Future<ByteStream> getStream(Request request) async {
  final client = Client();
  StreamedResponse response = await client.send(request);
  return response.stream;
}
```

`sse_stream_web.dart`: Get stream on web:

```dart
import 'package:fetch_client/fetch_client.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

Future<ByteStream> getStream(Request request) async {
  final FetchClient fetchClient = FetchClient(mode: RequestMode.cors);
  final FetchResponse response = await fetchClient.send(request);
  return response.stream;
}
```

Conditional import:

```dart
import 'path/to/sse_stream.dart' if (dart.library.js) 'path/to/sse_client_web.dart';
```